# Java Queue evaluation order

Tags: java, guava, operator-precedence

I have the following code

```
myQueue.offer(new myObj(
    fcnA,
    Collections2.transform(...),
    Collections2.transform(...)
))
```

My question is at what point is `Collections2.transform(...)` evaluated?

My guess would that this does not happen until the creation of myObj is invoked from the queue. Is this correct?

Comment: We don't really have enough context to tell, to be honest - aside from anything else, it depends on what you mean by "At what point is `Collections2.transform(...)` evaluated" - if you've got actions within that transformation, it may well be that `transform` is executed, but that it returns a value which will execute the individual actions later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes, it will be evaluated when the constructor is invoked.

See the Java Language Specification (JLS), [15.12.4.2. Evaluate Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2), particularly the last 2 paragraphs and [Example 15.12.4.1-2. Evaluation Order During Method Invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#d5e26015).

Comment: That's true, but probably pretty irrelevant, as `Collections2.transform` does about nothing. It only creates a `TransformedCollection`, which is *lazy*. So you perfectly answered what the OP asked, but probably missed what they needs to know.

Comment: @maaartinus, you are free to vote me down for perfectly answering the question and not presuming to tell him what I think he needs to know.

Comment: No reason to downvote. I just wanted everyone looking at your answer to see that there's more to consider.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections2` looks like a Guava class. If so, then `transform()` returns a lazy collection, a live view into the source collection. All actions are evaluated when you actually acces the colections' elements through `Collection` interface (likely, when you iterate over the collections).

If you need to have a transformed copy of the collections, you need to make the copy yourself (e.g. `new ArrayList(Collections2.transform(...))` ).